# Is it true that $\sqrt{(a_1+b_1+c_1)(a_2+b_2+c_2)}\geq \sqrt{a_1a_2}+\sqrt{b_1b_2}+\sqrt{c_1c_2}$?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a_1,b_1,c_1,a_2,b_2,c_2$ be positive real numbers. Is it true that

> $\sqrt{(a_1+b_1+c_1)(a_2+b_2+c_2)}\geq \sqrt{a_1a_2}+\sqrt{b_1b_2}+\sqrt{c_1c_2}$

If this is true, then I will have proved an Olympiad problem. I couldn't find a counter-example.

Comment: visual proof for this would have been great. could someone do that?

Comment: @Nick the derivative proof below is in some sense "visual": you have that as you grow e.g. $a_1$, then the left-hand side grows as $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x(a_2+b_2+c_2)}$, while the right-hand side grows as $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x(a_2)}$, which is clearly less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square both sides (they are non-negative) and rewrite the terms:
$$\iff(\sqrt{a_1}\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{b_1}\sqrt{b_1}+\sqrt{c_1}\sqrt{c_1})(\sqrt{a_2}\sqrt{a_2}+\sqrt{b_2}\sqrt{b_2}+\sqrt{c_2}\sqrt{c_2})\ge(\sqrt{a_1}\sqrt{a_2}+\sqrt{b_1}\sqrt{b_2}+\sqrt{c_1}\sqrt{c_2})^2$$
This is precisely the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality applied on $(\sqrt{a_1},\sqrt{b_1},\sqrt{c_1})$ and $(\sqrt{a_2},\sqrt{b_2},\sqrt{c_2})$.

Comment: Thanks! Should have seen that! I was just scared about that inequality not being true I guess

Answer (score 0):

An alternative proof (to the "standard" Cauchy-Schwarz one) is to verify that the inequality holds (as an equality) when all the variables equal $0$; and that, when all variables are non-negative, the partial derivative of the left-hand side with respect to *any* variable equals or exceeds the partial derivative of the right-hand side (so, if you "grow" the variables from $0$ to whatever non-negative values you want, the "advantage" of the left-hand side can only grow).

In fact, by the same argument if all variables are strictly positive, the inequality becomes strict!

Note that this argument *does* require some care if you want to formalize it, because the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ with respect to $x$ diverges to $+\infty$ as $x$ converges to $0$.